# jwplayer events not firing

Tags: javascript, events, jwplayer

In the process of updating the video player for this website and I'm running into a problem. Can't get the event to fire on completion of the movie. Tried all the embedding options and scoured the API faq and forums. Does anyone know why this is not working. May want to peek at the source code. It's not pretty in there, but someone may see a conflict. I've checked the console.log in Firebug and it came up with no errors. Thanks in advance.

Dave

www.friedmanllp.com/home3.php

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
                        flashplayer: 'video/intro.swf',
                        id: 'playerID',
                        width: '545',
                        height: '380',
                        autostart: true,
                        events: {
                            onComplete: function(e) {
                                alert('Works');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try without e in onComplete event. For reference Check [this](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference) out

```
             <script type="text/javascript">
                jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
                    flashplayer: 'video/intro.swf',
                    id: 'playerID',
                    width: '545',
                    height: '380',
                    autostart: true,
                    events: {
                        onComplete: function() {
                            alert('Works');
                        }
                    }
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: I was putting the file as the player. First mistake...



        <script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
       flashplayer: 'video/player.swf',
       id: 'playerID',
       width: '545',
       height: '380',
       file: 'video/intro.swf',
       stretching: 'fill',
       controlbar: 'none',
       autostart: true,
       events: {
        onPlay: function() {
         alert('Works');
        }
       }
      });
     </script>


Got it working now with onPlay but not onComplete.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. The fix I found was to make sure the flashplayer and jwplayer.js urls are on the same domain as the page being loaded. If they do not match the video will still play but events do not fire.